# Wordpress parses wp_posts.post_content before rendering?

Tags: wordpress

I noticed that when I call the the_post() or the_content() function from my wordpress template, it automatically parses the database data to replace new lines with `<br/>`, wraps the text with `<p>` tags etc...There's probably some kind of "format" function within the_post() or the_content().

I wrote a query to directly get posts from the wp_posts.  I then print it out like

```
<?php
$results = $wp->get_results($sql)
foreach($results as $row) echo $row->post_content; ?>
```

Clearly, this data is not parsed by wordpress' "format" function.  What is the proper way to output this content such that it undergoes the same "formatting" functions as the_post() or the_content()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@dpelletier is right, and you can simply apply that function to the `$row->post_content` string.

If you want WordPress to do everything it would normally do on the content, including `wpautop` and parsing shortcode, use;

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $row->post_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `wpautop()`.

Only adds `<p>` and `<br/>`, so I'm not sure if there is another formatting function that would do anything else.